# Access parent method from a dynamically added child

Tags: angular, dynamic

I want to remove the `OverviewComponent` from `ExploreComponent` when it is clicked.

There is how I add this component:

```js
export class ExploreComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  onItemSelected() {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(OverviewComponent);
  }
}
```

```js
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  onClose() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself and for those who have the same problem there is how to do:

So I couldn't add an event on my component HTML element because it was dynamically added.

```html
<app-challenge-overview (closeEvent)="onCloseFromChild($event)"></app-challenge-overview>
```

So the solution was to get the `createComponent(...)` value and to subscribe an event like following.

```js
const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(OverviewComponent);
componentRef.instance.closeEvent.subscribe(() => {
    this.closeOverview();
});
```

Hope it helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the clear method to clear that component.

> this. viewContainerRef.clear();

Comment: I know that but from the child component I can't do that